# Spring 3 Annotations: xml-less Declarative Transaction Management

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am creating a purely annotation driven (xml-less) spring 3 application following the tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/)

And here's my configuration file

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("postgres");
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("gayle");
    return driverManagerDataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "studentJDBCTemplate")
public StudentJDBCTemplate studentJDBCTemplate() {
    StudentJDBCTemplate studentJDBCTemplate = new StudentJDBCTemplate();
    studentJDBCTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource());
    studentJDBCTemplate.setDataSourceTransactionManager(dataSourceTransactionManager());
    studentJDBCTemplate.setJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate());
    return studentJDBCTemplate;
}

@Bean
public DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager() {
    DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
    dataSourceTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return dataSourceTransactionManager;
}
```

Now I'm trying to do `declarative transaction management` hence my `create()` method inside `StudentJDBCTemplate`

```
public void create(String name, Integer age) {
    System.out.println("Creating!");
    String SQL = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(SQL, name, age);
    System.out.println("Created Record Name=" + name + " Age=" + age);
}
```

does not programmatically call the transaction manager.

How do I achieve this? Do I have to declare an `@Aspect` to do this? Is there any annotation that can automatically configure when to commit transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `@Transactional` annotation. [Here's the documentation for it.](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) Specifically, go to section 10.5.1. All you need to do is annotate the methods you want to have a transaction wrapped around with the annotation. With the annotation's values you can specify anything you want about the type of transaction.

Comment: Hi, I added `@Transactional` to my `create()` method inside the `StudentJDBCTemplate` class, now I'm getting `testApp(com.keeboi.samples.springexample.AppTest): No qualifying bean of type [com.keeboi.samples.springexample.templates.StudentJDBCTemplate] is defined` using Maven btw, and I've added the required dependencies. Do note that this runs well without `@Transactional`

Comment: Add `@EnableTransactionManagement` to your configuration class.

Comment: Already added `@EnableTransactionManagement` prior to this question but I'm still getting the error :(

Comment: In that case the problem is probably that JDBCTemplate is a class you should use, but not a class you should (presumably?) extend. Instead, try switching that `@Bean` to something like plain [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html). Also, note that that documentation specifically says there should be no need to subclass it. Then put your create method in a class annotated `@Repository` and `@Autowire` in your JdbcTemplate.